# Notification pressed to open up file in default app (android)

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-notifications

I've currently got a regular notification that tracks the progress of a download (of a song). Once the download is complete I'd like to make it so that if the user presses on the notification it opens up the song file in the default application that would handle that file type.

I've tried searching but I'm unsure as to how to work with the PendingIntent and the MIME type when using .setDataAndType(). Could someone please explain or provide some example code for how I could set up the intent to open up the file from a specific file path in the default app?

Thank you,
Daniel

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create the notification like this with the pending intent to open the default audio player

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    File file = new File("YOUR_SONG_URI"); // set your audio path 
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Download completed")
            .setContentText("Song name")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent).build();

    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

Comment: Why you create the file then get uri, you can directly parse path to uri

Answer (score 1):

please put this code inside your notification code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("content://media/internal/images/media"));
```

Change your Uri path to directory where songs are placed

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File("/sdcard/download/path/test.mp3");
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");
```

this intent should be the open action of the notification. Since you said song so MIME will be audio/* or else you can use AndroidMimeTypeMap to get the mime type from file extention.

I have used this code it opens the "open action using" window. If you have set default app on your phone or tablet it will open the default app.